# Un équivalent du mot anglais « application » pour une procédure administrative

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

Je cherche un mot en français courant qui pourrait remplacer « application » en anglais, dans le contexte où il s'agit d'une procédure administrative, impliquant dossiers et paiements…

Comment: On peut utiliser simplement le mot ***dossier***.

Comment: @Begueradj , le dossier est plus un élément de la procédure que la procédure elle-même.

Answer (score 8):

Il s'agit d'une **candidature**, pour un cas personnel.

Ou d'une **demande** pour un cas administratif quelconque, ou **requête**. En cas de problème (si l'on n'est pas d'accord), on emploie plutôt **recours** ou **contestation**.

Applicant se traduit par pétitionnaire. Mais on n'emploie pas pétition.

Le terme administratif officiel en France est **saisine**, très peu usité car peu connu. Il va peut-être connaître un regain avec le concept de saisine par voie électronique (voir point suivant).

A noter que le mot **procédure** revient en force, avec la montée en puissance des technologies dématérialisées et web: on parle de **télé-procédures**: faire une télé-procédure, ou faire une procédure *en ligne*.

Le terme employé pour le demandeur évolue: d'assujetti, il passe à administré, pétitionnaire, ou impétrant (pour obtenir un diplome, certificat, ...)

Answer (score 1):

*Procédure administrative* ou *Démarche administrative* reste le plus adapté.

Il n'y a pas de mot propre à une démarche administrative. Si vous utilisez juste *démarche*, la phrase perdra son contexte, et vous supposez que l'interlocuteur sait que vous êtes en train de réaliser une *démarche administrative*.

Comment: une démarche dans le langage courant est presque toujours une démarche administrative (que cela soit avec l'administration ou tout organisme). Les autres emplois relèvent d'un langage plus soutenu, sont moins concrets et sont eux généralement suivis d'une précision (une démarche personnelle, singulière, ...)